# "Direct Response with Node.js" - Sending HTTP response with different Node.js process (different than main process)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, multiprocessing

Using Node.js servers, I am wondering if it is both possible and recommended to send an HTTP response from a delegated worker process, instead of the main process. These worker processes could be Node.js servers themselves, or simply Node.js child processes that communicate via IPC.

I don't think the cluster core module https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html can do what I want to do, because in that model, all the workers are listening on the same port, and they process all requests on behalf of the master process. What I am looking for is one main Node.js process that responds to all HTTP requests, perhaps does the authentication and processes some requests, but is also capable of delegating data-intensive or CPU intensive requests to a worker pool.

Imagine that we have a GET request for a large amount of data, say 2-3MBs.

We have at least 3 possible scenarios:

1. The main process receives the request, asks the database for the large amount of data and then sends the data back to the requestor.
2. Main process receives the request, sends some data to a worker process using IPC, the worker gets the data from the DB does some heavy operations, and then the worker uses IPC to send all of the 3MBs of data back to the main process, which then sends back the response.
3. The main process receives the request, sends as small amount of info as possible about the request stream to the worker, the worker does all the work and the worker sends back the HTTP response.

I am particularly curious about making #3 possible.

A simple depiction of scenario 3 is below:

[image]

(Just to be clear, I don't want 3 responses for one request, I am just trying to show that a worker could possibly send the response on behalf of the main process).

Anyone know how this might work with Node.js? How it might work in other languages? Normally I have no problems with the Node.js concurrency model, but with some types of data, using the Cluster module is probably not the best way to achieve the highest levels of concurrency.

I believe one term for this model is "direct response", meaning the worker responds directly to the request. And perhaps it's possible to simply use the cluster core module https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html for this.

Comment: I had somewhat similar idea not too long ago but after extensive search I ended up using nginx as a load balancer which looks like what you're trying to achieve with this but without spinning up the whole app. I'd be interested to know about the solution too if anyone has any.

Comment: sure, thanks, I think cluster.setupMaster might be able to do what I want to, but I am not sure yet, see: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_setupmaster_settings

Comment: for example, see the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771516/using-cluster-in-a-node-module/24463511#comment59142347_24463511

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it is both possible and recommended to send an HTTP response from a delegated worker process

Yes, this is possible and probably the easiest most common way to scale out your application servers.  Unlike IPC, it can work across hosts over a network.  (It will also work locally if you want it to... but do make sure you actually are CPU-bound in your application.  Despite JavaScript itself being single-threaded, most of the libraries for IO and some NPM modules use thread pools.)

There's no reason to use Node.js as the server load balancing between the backend servers.  Node.js is better for your application server.  For something just proxying HTTP requests, I'd use Nginx or similar.  Nginx can efficiently handle all the dealing with the client, and can be easily configured to load balance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to exploit multiple processors in your machine(s) (executing Node by itself only uses a single process), just use PM2:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

PM2 starts various instances of your application on the processors you dictate to PM2. If you application is stateless (as it ideally is using Node), an instance of your app will run on each processor and PM2 will do the routing.

If I can verbally redraw the diagram you posted for scenario 3, PM2 would take the place of "MAIN" and "W" would be replaced with your app and no need to worry about workers and forking.

We use PM2 in production and it performs well for us.